# error:command line option 'e' [from -dev] is not understood in combination with other options

Tags: command-line

I ran this command to install the packages for PetaLinux on my Ubuntu 20.04 LTS:

```
sudo apt-get install -y gcc git make net-tools libncurses5-dev tftpd zlib1g-dev \
  libssl-dev flex bison libselinux1 gnupg wget diffstat chrpath socat xterm autoconf \
  libtool tar unzip texinfo zlib1g-dev gcc-multilib build-essential -dev zlib1g:i386 \
  screen pax gzip
```

```
error:command line option 'e' [from -dev] is not understood in combination with other options.
```

I am new to PetaLinux and Ubuntu, hence any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `build-essential -dev` should probably not be a space in there

Comment: It is also just `build-essential`.  There is no `build-essential-dev`.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like there was simply an error in copying the command.

According to the [PetaLinux Tools Documentation Reference Guide UG1144 (v2018.3) December 5, 2018](https://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/sw_manuals/xilinx2018_3/ug1144-petalinux-tools-reference-guide.pdf), the correct command should be:

```
sudo apt-get install -y gcc git make net-tools libncurses5-dev tftpd zlib1g-dev libssl-dev flex bison libselinux1 gnupg wget diffstat chrpath socat xterm autoconf libtool tar unzip texinfo zlib1g-dev gcc-multilib build-essential libsdl1.2-dev libglib2.0-dev zlib1g:i386 screen pax gzip
```

or (with some line contiuations for clarity)

```
sudo apt-get install -y gcc git make net-tools libncurses5-dev tftpd \
  zlib1g-dev libssl-dev flex bison libselinux1 gnupg wget diffstat \
  chrpath socat xterm autoconf libtool tar unzip texinfo zlib1g-dev \
  gcc-multilib build-essential libsdl1.2-dev libglib2.0-dev zlib1g:i386 \
  screen pax gzip
```

Somehow, your command managed to excise the string `libsdl1.2-dev libglib2.0`, leaving characters `-dev` which the `apt-get` command is parsing as a sequence of single-letter options `-d`, `-e` and `-v`; the first and last of these are actually supported options (although they don't make sense in this context) however `-e` is not a valid option - hence the error message.

Answer (score 0):

Second [bac0n](https://askubuntu.com/users/986805/bac0n)  the `-dev` makes `apt` think that they are some form of flag.